# MessageBox stays hidden until the parent form refocuses

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, messagebox

I'm implementing a custom control that provides public events to be handled from an outer class, i.e. the main form.

The main form can handle those events (in my case it is an advanced TabControl).

An excerpt of my custom control:

```
public class FlatTabControlEx : TabControl {
  public delegate void OnTabCloseQueryDelegate(int tabIndex, TabPage tabPage);
  public event OnTabCloseQueryDelegate TabCloseQuery;

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    DrawControl(e.Graphics);
    base.OnPaint(e);
  }

  protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e) {
    var imageRect = GetImageRectangle()
    bool mouseOver = imageRect.Contains(GetMousePos());         
    if (mouseOver) {
      if (TabCloseQuery != null) {
        TabCloseQuery(i, TabPages[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is how I handle that event:

```
public partial class TestForm : Form {
  public TestForm() {
    InitializeComponent();

    _flatTabControlEx.TabCloseQuery += (index, tabPage) => {
      if (MessageBox.Show("Close tab with title " + tabPage.Text, "Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes) {
        _flatTabControlEx.TabPages.Remove(tabPage);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Somehow, the messagebox gets hidden (by its main form?) and only shows up when the main form loses and regains focus. Providing a different owner didn't seem to help.

How can I handle this case and how is the behaviour caused?

**Edit 1**: Added some minimalized code above.

**Edit 2**: I noticed that it's actually my control that is drawn over the MessageBox. How can I determine when to draw it?

Comment: Quacks like a threading problem.  Post code that reproduces this behavior.

Comment: I have not implemented any custom threading. I override the default OnPaint, may that be the cause? Anyways, code above has been added.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with datagridview cellpainting event.
What to do is avoiding repetitions.

when you leave a control, some events such as validate, paint etc are triggered.

For the case, when messsage box is opened,the control reviews his tasks and start doing. İf there is a data format mistake stop process, İf there is a paint task keep the parent form on top, so message box stays behind.

This was my solution (Winforms but it should be the same)

```
Public Class HybridDataGridView
Inherits DataGridView
WithEvents NewDataGridViewTextBox As New TextBox
Private NoFocus As Integer = 0

 Private Sub HybridDataGridView_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.LostFocus
    NoFocus = 1
 End Sub
 Private Sub HybridDataGridView_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.GotFocus
    NoFocus = 0
  End Sub
 Private Sub HybridDataGridView_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles Me.CellPainting
    If Me.CurrentCell Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim Kalem As Pen
    If e.ColumnIndex = Me.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex And e.RowIndex = Me.CurrentCell.RowIndex Then
        If NoFocus = 0 Then
           Kalem = New Pen(Color.Black, 1)
           e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, True)
           e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds)
         End if
      End if

  End sub
End Class
```